# Create object class in another class and calling methods the created class inside Base class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a few class and one them is *MainClass* class.

```
class MainClass {
public:

    MainClass() {
    }


    void start() {
        foo1.start();
        foo2.start();

    }

private:
    First foo1; //I would like have here reference to First
    Second foo2; // and Second class
};
```

This is my *First* class. The *Second* class is the same as *First*.

```
class First {
public:

    First() {
    }

    void start() {
        std::thread(&First::receive, this);
    }

    void receive() {
        //...
    }
};
```

In main function I have this:

```
    int main(){
        MainClass object;
        object.start();
    }
```

I would like to run *start()* methods from *First* and *Second* class when *MainClass* object has been created and I call *start()* method on this object.

I get error:

```
error: field ‘foo1’ has incomplete type
error: field ‘foo2’ has incomplete type
```

But if I do pointer to First and Second:

```
...
First *foo1;
Second *foo2;
...
```

programs compiles successfully when I run program in the console I get  "Segmentation fault".

Comment: `MainClass::start` is private. You can't call it. You also have to declare `First` and `Second` before using them in `MainClass`. Having said that, what's your question? What's not working right? You can just do what you want, as can be seen [here](http://ideone.com/thHLfB).

Comment: My mistake, start() method should be public. I corrected and added more info.

Comment: *You also have to declare First and Second before using them in MainClass*

Comment: I have declarations class First; and class Second; in place where I use them.

Comment: That's because a forward declaration is not enough. Have you looked at the working example I posted?

Comment: _"This is my First class. The Second class is the same as First."_ Then why is it _not_ `First`? Why do you have two identical classes?

Comment: _"when I run program in the console I get 'Segmentation fault'."_ You did not show us the program so how are we supposed to debug it for you?